# How to set expires_in an Angular 8 application?

Tags: angular, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using an Anguar 8 application and we use Google API for authentication.
The problem is, if user is logged in but does not use the system for an hour or so and then comes back, the system crashes (apparently, the token expires).

What I want to achieve here is, on expiry f token, I want to show a message. I have been reading to GAPI docs and also looked into the localstorage oauth, came accross a **expires_in** element of OAUTH.

Can someone tell me, how to set this Expires_in manually (for testing purpose) so that I can timeout the token quickly, put my message in and test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend is that anyways you have to check the exiration date (expires_in) in the token. Instead of checking it just hardcode something that is suitable for testing purposes.

What I usually do in such cases is that I create a background running job which automatically checks the token for expire. If certain condition is met I send a refresh token request.(Eg the token expires in 5 mins)